# Center input-group in column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 5 and I have created a box with a text and an input-group, like the following:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      Enter your email address to receive notifications about the product.
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <form>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" aria-label="Your Email Address" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="button-addon2">Start Monitoring</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `input-group` is not aligned with the text. Any suggestions why? I am already centering all columns.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      Enter your email address to receive notifications about the product.
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <form>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" aria-label="Your Email Address" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="button-addon2">Start Monitoring</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have a `<form>` tag inside `input-group`. It should be otherwise. Inputs and Buttons should directly reside inside `input-group` in bootstrap.